# What does mysqldump do when trying to restore a database?|

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to find a good way to back up and restore a database and came upon the `mysqldump`.  I've been using the command prompt to access the executable and I'm able to create a back up of the database in an sql file using the command:

```
mysqldump.exe -u [username] -p [databasename] -h localhost > [path]\backup.sql
```

then I enter my password for it to execute.
Incase it wasn't understood:

```
[username]=my username for accessing the database  
[databasename]=my name for the database that I'm trying to back up  
[path]=the folder path to where I want to save my back up.
```

With this command I'm able to create a back up and I've looked and found that the way to restore it would just be to flip the `> to <` so you would get this:

```
mysqldump.exe -u [username] -p [databasename] -h localhost > [path]\backup.sql
```

then I enter my password for it to execute.
When it executes it prints out what it's dumping (doesn't create new tables if I deleted some that were supposed to be restored).  I think it only adds values not already in the table since I added a row and it wasn't deleted when I tried restoring a previous version of the database.
I can execute the backup.sql file normally using a client or command prompt commands, but I just want to understand why the `mysqldump` isn't doing what I expect.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqldump` is for backup only, you can't use it to load the data from dump. `mysqldump` produces a dump file, which just contains SQL commands necessary to recreate database structure and repopulate it with data.

To restore feed the dump into `mysql.exe`.

When you do

```
mysql -u[username] -p[root_password] [database_name] < dumpfile.sql
```

you basically login into MySQL, then you ask it to perform all the SQL operations saved in the `dumpfile.sql` It's that simple.

Comment: Then what is this site actually trying to say when it shows an example to restore a database?  http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/

Comment: @LongPhan: the same thing I told you. None of their examples tells you to use `mysqldump` to load data into database.

Comment: You still haven't answered the question presented in reply to your answer.  What does the code on the site actually do?  It's apparent I don't understand the concept of "restoring" as they put it.  I am asking what is it actually doing.

Comment: @LongPhan: I updated the answer with some more details. See if it makes more sense to you now

Comment: I see, it seems that I misread the site.  For some reason the site seemed to convey the solution that the mysqldump command was being used for loading so my mind filled in the command with mysqldump and now I realize it says mysql instead.